# Change date format on fetch MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, date-formatting

When fetching the default timestamps the format is `2021-10-07T11:16:44.988Z`. I want it to be like `dd/mm/YYYY`. I want to achieve it without using a loop.

Comment: Use `{ $dateToString: { format: "%d/%m/%Y", date: "<your timestamp field>" } }`

Comment: It worked. Is there a way to format it as `18th October, 2021`? I did not find it on documentation.

Comment: No, local names are not supported natively. You would need to use a 3rd party library, e.g. [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a sales collection with the following document:

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "item" : "abc",
  "price" : 10,
  "quantity" : 2,
  "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T08:15:39.736Z")
}
```

The following aggregation uses $dateToString to return the date field as formatted strings:

```
db.sales.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $project: {
          yearMonthDayUTC: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } },
           
       }
     }
   ]
)
```

The operation returns the following result:

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "yearMonthDayUTC" : "2014-01-01"
}
```

[Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)